# Grails 2.0 and the Flot plugin... Cannot get it to work

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

Can anyone point me to why the following will not output any graph.  I have the flot plugin installed and using Grails 2.0 so jquery is the default...

```
<head>
    <flot:resources includeJQueryLib="false"/>
    <title>Performance Graphs for: ${data[0]?.sn}</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
</head>
<body>
    <g:javascript>
        var ingest = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

        var options = {
            lines: { show: true },
            points: { show: true }
        };
    </g:javascript>

    <flot:plot id="test" stype="width: 600px; height: 300px" 
          data="ingest" option="options" />       
</body>
```

Comment: I get a blank page...(well with my site header merged in)... Nothing else... Didnt realize I needed to accept answers - went back and should have taken care of that

Comment: Cool, thanks for doing that :-)  What do you get in the source code of the generated page?  Does the HTML just stop at a point?  Is the flot code inserted at all?

Comment: It's probably trying to call flot before the jquery scripts are loaded in to the browser (they should be injected into the page by the resources plugin)...  Checking the source and a tool like FireBug should help work out if this is the case

Comment: It seems the problem is that I just cannot type... in <flot:plot I should have specified "style" and not "stype"...

Comment: Or maybe not... Now all the code gets generated and the div as well, but still no chart.  It does seem to gen the proper code <div style="width: 600px; height: 300px;" id="test"/><script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function () {jQuery.plot(jQuery("#test"),ingest);});</script>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Flot and Grails 2.1.1.

The graph started to appear when I have have added `<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>` tag to the page header and moved `<flot:resources includeJQueryLib="false"/>` into the body of the page. The following snippet shows how:

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'chart.label', default: 'Chart')}" />
    <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
</head>
<body>
    <flot:resources includeJQueryLib="false"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

instead of
var ingest = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];
use it like
var ingest = [[[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]]];